# modular curves with complex multiplication

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-multiplication

Is the complete list of values of $N$ for which the modular curve $X_0(N)$ has complex multiplication?

I guess the answer is no...

Are there at least some examples known? The only one which comes to my mind is $N=11$ (if I am not mistaken $X_0(11)$ is a CM elliptic curve).

Comment: Was that meant to be "is the complete list known"?

Comment: $X_0(11)$ is not a CM elliptic curve: CM elliptic curves have potential good reduction, whereas elliptic curves of conductor $11$ have multiplicative reduction at $11$.

Comment: Suppose $X_0(N)$ has genus $>0$ ($N=11,14,15,17$ or $N>18$ except $N=25$). If $p|N$ with $p>7$ but $p\ne 13$ then $J_0(N)$ has the quotient $J_0(p)$ with toric reduction at $p$, so CM over $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$ is ruled out by Kestutis' argument. Thus, you just have to handle $N$ whose prime factors are in $\{2,3,5,7,13\}$ with $N$ not in the genus-0 list. For $N = 27, 32, 49$, $X_0(N)$ is an elliptic curve with geometric CM by $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_3)$, $\mathbf{Q}(i)$, $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$ respectively. I am sure that others on MO with more computational expertise can address the rest.

Comment: wow, thank you very much! Do you have some reference for the statement about $J_0(N)$ and the quotient $J_0(p)$ with toric reduction at p? Do you know of any example in genus at least 2?

Comment: The degeneracy map $X_0(N)\rightarrow X_0(p)$ over $\mathbf{Q}$ induces $J_0(N)\twoheadrightarrow J_0(p)$ over $\mathbf{Q}$ by Albanese functoriality. Toric reduction for $J_0(p)$ at $p$ is a consequence of the determination of the minimal regular proper model of $X_0(p)$ over $\mathbf{Z}_{(p)}$, due to the relationship (proved by Raynaud) between the Neron model of a Jacobian and the relative Picard scheme of the minimal regular proper model of a curve over a dvr, combined with the description of the special fiber of that relative Pic. See Ch. 9 of "Neron Models", especially 9.2/8 and 9.7.